# Clearing gridview upon certain condition in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

on textbox blank, i wanted to clear my gridview source

But i was not able to do it in vb.net.

After referring several answers i tried following unsuccessfull attempts:

`grdUsers.rows.clear()` : Does not work with vb.net

```
grdUsers.DataSource=""

grdUsers.columns.clear()
```

But it does not worked out.

Please help me to clear my datasource of gridview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your DataGridView is bound to a DataSource and you want to clear it then you can use the `Nothing` keyword followed by a `DataBind()`.

```
grdUsers.DataSource = Nothing
grdUsers.DataBind()
```

Here is [more information on the DataBind() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983981/why-is-the-databind-method-necessary).

---

If you want to clear your rows when the text is empty in TextBox1, you would create a TextChanged event for your textbox ...

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim = "" Then 
       grdUsers.DataSource = Nothing
       grdUsers.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: grdUsers.DataBind() afterwards might help as well

Comment: @ShrimantBajiraoPeshawe-I Try it with the `DataBind()`. See edit.