# ASP.NET C# : How to load a dataview object using sql classes via the code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I know I can drag/drop an `sqlDataSource` object onto my webform and then get my connection string from my webconfig file and link it and done... But I don't want to do it that way. I want to do it programmatically.

as it can be done in a windows form app like so:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionDev"].ConnectionString);
string command = "SELECT * FROM DUMMY";
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command, conn);

SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
dgvDelete.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

How can I do this in a web form?

I think I have to use the `sqlDataSource` object and set it up that way but I don't know how.

Can someone show me?

Answer (score 0):

if you want see the data in the `GridView` control you must add this:

```
dgvDelete.DataBind();
```

For more details check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983981/why-is-the-databind-method-necessary)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you can create a function to return a DataTable which contains the data your want to view (or wherever you want to put the code).  Then set the GridView control's datasource to your datatable then databind.

yourGridView.DataSource = yourDataTable

yourGridView.DataBind()