# asp datagridview population dosnt working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I am encountering a strange problem in the past 3 days, although that query return data the datagrid does not show either any data or any columns (I am fairly new to ASP but I dont think the code has any problem).

here is the code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet UserInfoFromDB = FillTableInfo();
            GridViewData.DataSource = UserInfoFromDB.Tables[0];
            GridViewData.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        }
```

the load calling this function to get all the data, I have already tested the output and its returning the data as it should be but the datagrid seems empty.

```
public DataSet FillTableInfo(){
            var Query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[orders] ;";
            SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, CreateConnectionstring());
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(DataAdapter);
            DataSet DataSetVariable = new DataSet();
            DataAdapter.Fill(DataSetVariable);
            return DataSetVariable;
        }
```

I have changed only the gridview id so far

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you add the markup from the aspx page relative to your GridViewData element?

Comment: try with IsPostback Property on PageLoad

Comment: seems you missed to add  GridViewData.DataBind();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use the Databind() method

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet UserInfoFromDB = FillTableInfo();
        GridViewData.DataSource = UserInfoFromDB.Tables[0];
        GridViewData.DataBind();
        GridViewData.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much , I will put this article here for anyone who might need some further explenation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983981/why-is-the-databind-method-necessary